# Who are the "Fallen Fifty"?

Tags: harry-potter, the-cursed-child

In Harry Potter and the Cursed Child, Harry says...

> **HARRY:** *I shouldn’t have survived — it was my destiny to die — even Dumbledore thought so — and yet I lived. I beat Voldemort. All
>   these people — all these people — my parents, Fred, **the Fallen
>   Fifty** — and it’s me that gets to live? How is that? All this damage
>   — and it’s my fault.*

**Who were the "Fallen Fifty"?**

Answer (score 31):

This probably refers to the fifty people who died fighting Voldemort in the Battle of Hogwarts.

> They moved Voldemort’s body and laid it in a chamber off the Hall,
> away from the bodies of Fred, Tonks, Lupin, Colin Creevey, and fifty
> others who had died fighting him.
>
> <sub>—*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*</sub>

Interestingly, the previous paragraph indicates that the “Fallen 50" is an peculiar choice of words, since in reality at least 54 people had died in that battle.

Comment: Can you list them... now is the question

Comment: @bleh - I could provide a partial list, but I fear most are not named.

Comment: Per the wiki "*Besides Severus Snape, Fred Weasley, Vincent Crabbe, Colin Creevey, Lavender Brown, and Remus and Nymphadora Lupin, **all the other casualties were unidentified individuals**, although Gregory Goyle died in place of Crabbe in the final film as well. It is possible that the Unidentified Hogwarts students killed on the Seventh Floor and Unidentified wizard killed at the Quad battlements are part of the Fallen Fifty*" - "[**The Fallen Fifty**](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/The_Fallen_Fifty)"

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44932/discussion-on-answer-by-adamant-who-are-the-fallen-fifty).

Comment: Either 46 or 54 could easily be referred to as "fifty", by rounding or approximation in casual speech. It's not that peculiar.

Answer (score -1):

There were 54 casualties on the Hogwarts Defenders side

There were 54 casualties during the Battle of Hogwarts. Here is who I think fought valiantly to defend the castle and did not make it home. Here is who died in the battle and their killer. (Note = Many of these "deaths" are ambiguous as to whether they lived or not but here is just my guess. These are just people I believe who died, of which I have identified the identities of 29 out of 54 fatalities. Their sacrifices are not in vain however, as Voldemort and his Death Eaters were defeated, and peace was restored to the Wizarding War thanks to their valiant efforts.

Adults and other fatalities (7 Known Fatalities)

1. Remus Lupin
2. Nymphadora Tonks
3. Severus Snape
4. Professor Aurora Sinistra (Astronomy)
5. Dedalus Diggle
6. Elphias Doge
7. Unidentified Male Wizard killed on Quad Battlements

Dumbledores Army Members/Students (By House) (22 known fatalities)

*A. Gryffindor*

1. Fred Weasley
2. Lavender Brown
3. Pavarti Patil
4. Colin Creevey
5. Dennis Creevey
6. Nigel Wolpert
7. Alice Tolipan
8. Alicia Spinnet
9. Unidentified Female

*B. Hufflepuff*

1. Ernie Macmillan
2. Justin Finch-Fletchley
3. Susan Bones
4. Megan Jones
5. Luca Caruso
6. Wayne Hopkins
7. Unidentified Female

*C.Ravenclaw*

1. Terry Boot
2. Anthony Goldstein
3. Unidentified Male

*D. Unidentified House*

1-3. 3 Undentified Students on 7th Floor

Comment: Of the ambiguous ones, how did you decide they were dead? Adding some more insight into evidence you used to come to your conclusions would be interesting.

Comment: Just the majority of these people were left with open ended fates. Therefore I am assuming that they were among the fallen fifty (of those who fought on Harry/Dumbledores side). JK Rowling never said explicitly. This is just my hypothetical guess as to who defended the school and never made it home. If I wrote the book instead of Ms. Rowling this is who I would have killed off, I probably would have killed off more death eaters aside from Voldemort and Bellatrix also.

Comment: Ok, but while it's interesting this site pride's itself on the factual content it produces. It's a Q&A site not a discussion site, as such we look for evidence to support any answers produced and not answers with personal preference or unsupported guesses. Unfortunately you didn't write the book, and as such your opinion doesn't really count.

Answer (score -3):

Colin Creevey

Fred Weasley

Seamus Finnigan(possibly)

Hannah Abbott(possibly)

Lavender Brown

Vincent Crabbe Jr.(movies)

Gregory Goyle Jr.

Remus Lupin

Severus Snape

Nymphadora Tonks

Unidentified Wizard killed during Quad (possibly Dedalus Diggle)

Unidentified Witch killed on Seventh Floor(possibly Alice Tolipan)

Unidentified Wizard killed on Seventh Floor(possibly Dennis Creevey)

Unidentified Witch killed on Seventh Floor(possibly Rose Zinners)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  An explanation of why you think the "possibly" ones should be included here would help (also for the tentative identifications).

Comment: By my count, that's 14. Granted, that's closer to 50 than it is to 100 or 100,000, but mathematically, one would be hard pressed to consider that "50" within any common definition of rounding.